# Update a base table with a staging table that references the columns to update[REDSHIFT]

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I am having trouble with the below example.

I have 2 tables, snapshot and staging. Staging contains the following columns:

```
|person_id|column_changed|new_value|

|1        |     color    | orange  |
|1        |     sport    | football|
```

Snapshot contains the following columns:

```
|person_id| color| sport |

|1        | blue | tennis|
```

I need to update the column(value in the changed_column from staging) in the snapshot table with the new_value in the staging table.

The query below is what I would do manually in this simplified example.

```
update snapshot a
set 
a.color='orange',
a.sport='football'
from staging b
where a.person_id=b.person_id
```

Is there a way to  relatively reference the required columns rather than manually supplying the update columns + fields?  Is there a way to reference the a.'columns_changed'=b.'new_value' in the set predicate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to do what you want.  The first is multiple updates:

```
update snapshot s
    set color = st.new_value
    from staging st
    where st.person_id = s.person_id and st.column_changed = 'color';

update snapshot s
    set sport = st.new_value
    from staging st
    where st.person_id = s.person_id and st.column_changed = 'sport';
```

Or, pre-aggregate and do all at once:

```
update snapshot s
    set color = coalesce(st.color, s.color),
        sport = coalesce(st.sport, s.sport)
    from (select st.person_id,
                 max(case when st.column_changed = 'color' then st.new_value end) as color,
                 max(case when st.column_changed = 'sport' then st.new_value end) as sport
          from staging st
          group by st.person_id
         ) st
    where st.person_id = s.person_id;
```

(This actually assumes that the new value is never `NULL`.)

What is the challenge?  Well, a join to `staging` would cause some rows to be updated multiple times -- say once for color and once for sport.  Unfortunately (or fortunately perhaps), `update`s don't accumulate.  Only one is executed, arbitrarily.

So, your first approach just isn't going to work.  The above two approaches are what come to my mind.  Perhaps there is a third way.

Comment: Thanks very much for this. Just a quick question. Should st.column_changed = 'color' be st.column_changed  in('color','sport')?

Comment: @pippadupree . . . No, that condition doesn't apply at all.